# Is it known how many graphs on $n$ vertices have the same characteristic equations?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Is there a formula that shows how many simple graphs on $n$ vertices have the same characteristic equations?

To be crystal-clear, I am *not* asking about a function that says how many graphs share *the same* characteristic equation - I am asking about a function that says how many graphs share *a* characteristic function. So, for a hypothetical example, say our function is $C(x)$, and for $n$ vertices, $P(G_1)=f(x), P(G_2)=f(x), P(G_3)=g(x), P(G_4)=g(x),$ and $P(G_5)=g(x)$, and these are the only instances where the graphs share characteristic equations. I would then expect $C(n)=5$.

Comment: What do you mean by "characteristic equation" - the characteristic polynomial of the adjacency matrix, or something else?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of the adjacency matrix, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the characteristic polynomial of two graphs is the same (with respect to the adjacency matrix), we say that they are *cospectral* (with respect to the adjacency matrix), because this is equivalent to asking that the eigenvalues are the same.

A graph is *determined by spectrum* (DS) if it is not cospectral with any other graph. So, you are looking for the number of non-DS graphs on $n$ vertices.

Thee [OEIS sequence A099883](http://oeis.org/A099883) gives the values of your function $C(n)$ for $n=1, 2, \dots, 9$, but this appears to be a duplicate of [A006608](http://oeis.org/A006608), which goes up to $n=12$.

For more general bounds, see the paper [*Which graphs are determined by their spectrum?*](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(03)00483-X) by van Dam and Haemers, and the book *Spectra of Graphs* by Brouwer and Haemers. We have an asymptotic lower bound on $C(n)$: if $g_n$ is the total number of non-isomorphic graphs on $n$ vertices, then
$$
   C(n) \ge n^3 g_{n-1}\left( \frac1{24} - o(1)\right).
$$
Unfortunately, $g_n$ is much larger than $n^3 g_{n-1}$: asymptotically, $g_n \sim 2^{n(n-1)/2}/n!$. So this doesn't tell us much about what fraction of the $n$-vertex graphs are DS.

Brouwer and Haemers have this to say about upper bounds on $C(n)$:

> It seems more likely that almost all graphs are DS, than that almost all graphs are non-DS. Yet much less is known about DS graphs than about non-DS graphs. For example, we do not know of a satisfying counterpart to the lower bounds for non-DS graphs...